# Ionic/Cordova app not loading home.page.html

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I have a simple Ionic app that takes a photo with the cordova camera plugin, and then uploads it to firebase storage. I have set my root page as my home page (currently only page in my app) and when I run

```
ionic cordova emulate android -c -l
```

The ADV starts fine, the app builds successfully and launches, but no content loads, even though I have content in my home.page.html file. I am importing HomePage as './home/home.page' because I got errors any other way I did it, but I do not know if that is correct. I am new to ionic and cordova, so if this is a simple problem, I am sorry. Thank you for the help!

EDIT: Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from './home/home.page';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';

import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { IonicErrorHandler, IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';



import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

const firebaseConfig = {
  My firebase Config
 }

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     MyApp,
     HomePage
   ],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     IonicModule.forRoot({}),
     AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
     AngularFirestoreModule,
     AngularFireStorageModule
   ],
   bootstrap: [IonicApp],
   entryComponents: [
     MyApp,
     HomePage
   ],
   providers: [
     StatusBar,
     Camera,
     SplashScreen,
     {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
   ]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

And this is my home.page.html file:

```
<!--
  Generated template for the VisionPage page.
  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->

<ion-app>
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>



<ion-content padding>
  <ion-row>

    <ion-col col-12 text-center>

      <button ion-button icon-start (tap)="captureAndUpload()">
        <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
        Activate Cloud Vision
      </button>

    </ion-col>

    <ion-col col-12>
        <img width="100%" height="auto" [src]="image">
    </ion-col>

  </ion-row>

</ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: did you try doing `ionic serve`?

Comment: @IanP. I did try using ionic serve, and nothing was displayed in the browser, only the <app-root> tags in the served html.

Comment: are you able to show your app.module.ts file?

Comment: your app.module looks okay. were there any errors in the browser page logged in the dev tools (f12 in the browser page)?

Comment: @IanP. There were no errors anywhere, just a blank screen. I checked the console, and the output of the command.

Comment: are you also able to show your home.page.html file? I assume you have a component tag in it

Comment: @IanP. I have added the home.page.html file above. I thought it may have been an issue where the app.page.html was the main page, but no content I put there shows up either.